# No Link in a Events List

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can somebody help me please. I tried everything, but it doesn't work.
my html link disappears in "Theater für zwerge"

The original code come from: https://github.com/dellax/eventify
and my html: https://www.em-dsign.de/theater/termine.html

```
Html Code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<title>Theater Starter - Programme</title>
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/modern-business.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/sticky-footer-navbar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- FONT PATRICK -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Patrick+Hand" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Special+Elite" rel="stylesheet">   
<link href="css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- Calendar -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/eventify.css">
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/moment.js"></script>
<script src="js/eventify.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
<div class="container">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
<img src="images/Logo.png" width="150" height="30" alt=""></a>    
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="stuecke.html">Stücke</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="termine.html">Termine</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="staedte-Aachen.html">Städte</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="tickets.html">Tickets</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>

<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container">
<!-- Page Heading/Breadcrumbs -->
<ol class="breadcrumb">
<li class="breadcrumb-item">
<a href="index.html">Home</a>
</li>        
<li class="breadcrumb-item active">Termine</li>
</ol>
<!-- Header - set the background image for the header in the line below -->       
<!-- Portfolio Item Row -->
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
<p class="pB"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></p>
<p class="pB"><a href="termine-AAC.html">Aachen <img src="images/kr-aachen.png" alt="Aachen"></a></p>
<p class="pBr"><a href="#">Düren <img src="images/kr-dueren.png" alt="Düren"></a></p>
<p class="pBr"><a href="#">Eupen <img src="images/kr-eupen.png" alt="Eupen"></a></p>
<p class="pBr"><a href="#">Geilenkirchen <img src="images/kr-geilenkirchen.png" alt="Geilenkirchen"></a></p>
<p class="pBr"><a href="#">Heimbach <img src="images/kr-heimbach.png" alt="Heimbach"></a></p>
 <p class="pBr"><a href="#">Heinsberg <img src="images/kr-heinsberg.png" alt="Heinsberg"></a></p>
 <p class="pBr"><a href="#">Hückelhoven <img src="images/kr-hueckelhoven.png" alt="Hückelhoven"></a></p>
 <p class="pBr"><a href="#">St. Vith <img src="images/kr-st-vith.png" alt="St. Vith"></a></p>
 <p class="pBr"><a href="#">Übach-Palenberg <img src="images/kr-uebach.png" alt="Übach-Palenberg"></a></p>
 <p class="pBr"><a href="#">Würselen <img src="images/kr-wuerselen.png" alt="Würselen"></a></p>     
</div>  
<div class="col-md-8">
<div class="row">
       
<!-- Eventify -->
<div id="ei-events">
<p><strong>Termine</strong></p><br>      
<div class="ei-event" data-start="2021-03-02 16:00" data-end="2021-03-17 16:00" data-loc="Aachen / Ludwig Forum">
<div class="ei-name"><a href="zwerge.html">Theater für Zwerge</a></div>
<div class="ei-description">Tanz- und Soundperformance &nbsp; &nbsp ab 3 J.</div>
<a href="kontakt.html">link</a>
</div>
   
<div class="ei-event" data-start="2021-03-19 16:00" data-end="2021-03-22 17:00" data-loc="Aachen / Ludwig Forum">
<div class="ei-name">Ein GummiSchlauchspiel</div>
<div class="ei-description">Tanz- und Soundperformance &nbsp; &nbsp ab 3 J.</div>
</div>
       
<div class="ei-event" data-start="2021-04-23 11:00" data-end="2021-04-27 16:00" data-loc="Aachen / Ludwig Forum">
<div class="ei-name">Pffhhh Ein GummiSchlauchspiel</div>
<div class="ei-description">Tanz- und Soundperformance &nbsp; &nbsp ab 3 J.</div>
</div>                
</div><!-- / Events  -->                                  
</div><!-- / row -->
</div><!-- /col-md-8 -->      
</div><!-- / row -->    
</div>
<!-- /.container -->
<!-- Footer -->
<footer id="stickyfooter">
<div class="container">
<p class="m-0 text-center text-white">Copyright &copy; Your Website 2021</p>
</div>
<!-- /.container -->
</footer>

<script type="text/javascript">
$( "#ei-events" ).eventify({
theme: "",
locale: "en"
});
</script>
 
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/popper/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(window).scroll(function(){
var wscroll = $(this).scrollTop();
if(wscroll > 100){
$(".navbar").addClass("shrink-nav");
$(".logo").addClass("shrink-logo");
}
else{
$(".navbar").removeClass("shrink-nav");
$(".logo").removeClass("shrink-logo");
}
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here the js/script:
(function( $, undef )
{
if ( $.fn.dotdotdot )
{
return;
}

```
$.fn.dotdotdot = function( o )
{
if ( this.length == 0 )
{
$.fn.dotdotdot.debug( 'No element found for "' + this.selector + '".' );
return this;
}
if ( this.length > 1 )
{
return this.each(
function()
{
$(this).dotdotdot( o );
}
);
}

var $dot = this;
if ( $dot.data( 'dotdotdot' ) )
{
$dot.trigger( 'destroy.dot' );
}

$dot.data( 'dotdotdot-style', $dot.attr( 'style' ) || '' );
$dot.css( 'word-wrap', 'break-word' );
if ($dot.css( 'white-space' ) === 'nowrap')
{
$dot.css( 'white-space', 'normal' );
}

$dot.bind_events = function()
{
$dot.bind(
'update.dot',
function( e, c )
{
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();

opts.maxHeight = ( typeof opts.height == 'number' )
? opts.height
: getTrueInnerHeight( $dot );

opts.maxHeight += opts.tolerance;

if ( typeof c != 'undefined' )
{
if ( typeof c == 'string' || c instanceof HTMLElement )
{
c = $('<div />').append( c ).contents();
}
if ( c instanceof $ )
{
orgContent = c;
}
}

$inr = $dot.wrapInner( '<div class="dotdotdot" />' ).children();
$inr.contents()
.detach()
.end()
.append( orgContent.clone( true ) )
.find( 'br' )
.replaceWith( '  <br />  ' )
.end()
.css({
'height'    : 'auto',
'width'     : 'auto',
'border'    : 'none',
'padding'   : 0,
'margin'    : 0
});

var after = false,
trunc = false;

if ( conf.afterElement )
{
after = conf.afterElement.clone( true );
after.show();
conf.afterElement.detach();
}

if ( test( $inr, opts ) )
{
if ( opts.wrap == 'children' )
{
trunc = children( $inr, opts, after );
}
else
{
trunc = ellipsis( $inr, $dot, $inr, opts, after );
}
}
$inr.replaceWith( $inr.contents() );
$inr = null;

if ( $.isFunction( opts.callback ) )
{
opts.callback.call( $dot[ 0 ], trunc, orgContent );
}

conf.isTruncated = trunc;
return trunc;
}

).bind(
'isTruncated.dot',
function( e, fn )
{
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();

if ( typeof fn == 'function' )
{
fn.call( $dot[ 0 ], conf.isTruncated );
}
return conf.isTruncated;
}

).bind(
'originalContent.dot',
function( e, fn )
{
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();

if ( typeof fn == 'function' )
{
fn.call( $dot[ 0 ], orgContent );
}
return orgContent;
}

).bind(
'destroy.dot',
function( e )
{
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();

$dot.unwatch()
.unbind_events()
.contents()
.detach()
.end()
.append( orgContent )
.attr( 'style', $dot.data( 'dotdotdot-style' ) || '' )
.data( 'dotdotdot', false );
}
);
return $dot;
};  //  /bind_events

$dot.unbind_events = function()
{
$dot.unbind('.dot');
return $dot;
};  //  /unbind_events

$dot.watch = function()
{
$dot.unwatch();
if ( opts.watch == 'window' )
{
var $window = $(window),
_wWidth = $window.width(),
_wHeight = $window.height();

$window.bind(
'resize.dot' + conf.dotId,
function()
{
if ( _wWidth != $window.width() || _wHeight != $window.height() || !opts.windowResizeFix )
{
_wWidth = $window.width();
_wHeight = $window.height();

if ( watchInt )
{
clearInterval( watchInt );
}
watchInt = setTimeout(
function()
{
$dot.trigger( 'update.dot' );
}, 100
);
}
}
);
}
else
{
watchOrg = getSizes( $dot );
watchInt = setInterval(
function()
{
if ( $dot.is( ':visible' ) )
{
var watchNew = getSizes( $dot );
if ( watchOrg.width  != watchNew.width ||
watchOrg.height != watchNew.height )
{
$dot.trigger( 'update.dot' );
watchOrg = watchNew;
}
}
}, 500
);
}
return $dot;
};
$dot.unwatch = function()
{
$(window).unbind( 'resize.dot' + conf.dotId );
if ( watchInt )
{
clearInterval( watchInt );
}
return $dot;
};

var orgContent  = $dot.contents(),
opts        = $.extend( true, {}, $.fn.dotdotdot.defaults, o ),
conf        = {},
watchOrg    = {},
watchInt    = null,
$inr        = null;

if ( !( opts.lastCharacter.remove instanceof Array ) )
{
opts.lastCharacter.remove = $.fn.dotdotdot.defaultArrays.lastCharacter.remove;
}
if ( !( opts.lastCharacter.noEllipsis instanceof Array ) )
{
opts.lastCharacter.noEllipsis = $.fn.dotdotdot.defaultArrays.lastCharacter.noEllipsis;
}

conf.afterElement   = getElement( opts.after, $dot );
conf.isTruncated    = false;
conf.dotId          = dotId++;


$dot.data( 'dotdotdot', true )
.bind_events()
.trigger( 'update.dot' );

if ( opts.watch )
{
$dot.watch();
}

return $dot;
};

//  public
$.fn.dotdotdot.defaults = {
'ellipsis'          : '... ',
'wrap'              : 'word',
'fallbackToLetter'  : true,
'lastCharacter'     : {},
'tolerance'         : 0,
'callback'          : null,
'after'             : null,
'height'            : null,
'watch'             : false,
'windowResizeFix'   : true
};
$.fn.dotdotdot.defaultArrays = {
'lastCharacter'     : {
'remove'            : [ ' ', '\u3000', ',', ';', '.', '!', '?' ],
'noEllipsis'        : []
}
};
$.fn.dotdotdot.debug = function( msg ) {};


//  private
var dotId = 1;

function children( $elem, o, after )
{
var $elements   = $elem.children(),
isTruncated = false;

$elem.empty();

for ( var a = 0, l = $elements.length; a < l; a++ )
{
var $e = $elements.eq( a );
$elem.append( $e );
if ( after )
{
$elem.append( after );
}
if ( test( $elem, o ) )
{
$e.remove();
isTruncated = true;
break;
}
else
{
if ( after )
{
after.detach();
}
}
}
return isTruncated;
}
function ellipsis( $elem, $d, $i, o, after )
{
var isTruncated = false;

//  Don't put the ellipsis directly inside these elements
var notx = 'table, thead, tbody, tfoot, tr, col, colgroup, object, embed, param, ol, ul, dl, blockquote, select, optgroup, option, textarea, script, style';

//  Don't remove these elements even if they are after the ellipsis
var noty = 'script, .dotdotdot-keep';

$elem
.contents()
.detach()
.each(
function()
{

var e   = this,
$e  = $(e);

if ( typeof e == 'undefined' || ( e.nodeType == 3 && $.trim( e.data ).length == 0 ) )
{
return true;
}
else if ( $e.is( noty ) )
{
$elem.append( $e );
}
else if ( isTruncated )
{
return true;
}
else
{
$elem.append( $e );
if ( after )
{
$elem[ $elem.is( notx ) ? 'after' : 'append' ]( after );
}
if ( test( $i, o ) )
{
if ( e.nodeType == 3 ) // node is TEXT
{
isTruncated = ellipsisElement( $e, $d, $i, o, after );
}
else
{
isTruncated = ellipsis( $e, $d, $i, o, after );
}

if ( !isTruncated )
{
$e.detach();
isTruncated = true;
}
}

if ( !isTruncated )
{
if ( after )
{
after.detach();
}
}
}
}
);

return isTruncated;
}
function ellipsisElement( $e, $d, $i, o, after )
{
var e = $e[ 0 ];

if ( !e )
{
return false;
}

var txt         = getTextContent( e ),
space       = ( txt.indexOf(' ') !== -1 ) ? ' ' : '\u3000',
separator   = ( o.wrap == 'letter' ) ? '' : space,
textArr     = txt.split( separator ),
position    = -1,
midPos      = -1,
startPos    = 0,
endPos      = textArr.length - 1;

//  Only one word
if ( o.fallbackToLetter && startPos == 0 && endPos == 0 )
{
separator   = '';
textArr     = txt.split( separator );
endPos      = textArr.length - 1;
}

while ( startPos <= endPos && !( startPos == 0 && endPos == 0 ) )
{
var m = Math.floor( ( startPos + endPos ) / 2 );
if ( m == midPos )
{
break;
}
midPos = m;

setTextContent( e, textArr.slice( 0, midPos + 1 ).join( separator ) + o.ellipsis );

if ( !test( $i, o ) )
{
position = midPos;
startPos = midPos;
}
else
{
endPos = midPos;

//  Fallback to letter
if (o.fallbackToLetter && startPos == 0 && endPos == 0 )
{
separator   = '';
textArr     = textArr[ 0 ].split( separator );
position    = -1;
midPos      = -1;
startPos    = 0;
endPos      = textArr.length - 1;
}
}
}

if ( position != -1 && !( textArr.length == 1 && textArr[ 0 ].length == 0 ) )
{
txt = addEllipsis( textArr.slice( 0, position + 1 ).join( separator ), o );
setTextContent( e, txt );
}
else
{
var $w = $e.parent();
$e.detach();

var afterLength = ( after && after.closest($w).length ) ? after.length : 0;

if ( $w.contents().length > afterLength )
{
e = findLastTextNode( $w.contents().eq( -1 - afterLength ), $d );
}
else
{
e = findLastTextNode( $w, $d, true );
if ( !afterLength )
{
$w.detach();
}
}
if ( e )
{
txt = addEllipsis( getTextContent( e ), o );
setTextContent( e, txt );
if ( afterLength && after )
{
$(e).parent().append( after );
}
}
}

return true;
}
function test( $i, o )
{
return $i.innerHeight() > o.maxHeight;
}
function addEllipsis( txt, o )
{
while( $.inArray( txt.slice( -1 ), o.lastCharacter.remove ) > -1 )
{
txt = txt.slice( 0, -1 );
}
if ( $.inArray( txt.slice( -1 ), o.lastCharacter.noEllipsis ) < 0 )
{
txt += o.ellipsis;
}
return txt;
}
function getSizes( $d )
{
return {
'width' : $d.innerWidth(),
'height': $d.innerHeight()
};
}
function setTextContent( e, content )
{
if ( e.innerText )
{
e.innerText = content;
}
else if ( e.nodeValue )
{
e.nodeValue = content;
}
else if (e.textContent)
{
e.textContent = content;
}

}
function getTextContent( e )
{
if ( e.innerText )
{
return e.innerText;
}
else if ( e.nodeValue )
{
return e.nodeValue;
}
else if ( e.textContent )
{
return e.textContent;
}
else
{
return "";
}
}
function getPrevNode( n )
{
do
{
n = n.previousSibling;
}
while ( n && n.nodeType !== 1 && n.nodeType !== 3 );

return n;
}
function findLastTextNode( $el, $top, excludeCurrent )
{
var e = $el && $el[ 0 ], p;
if ( e )
{
if ( !excludeCurrent )
{
if ( e.nodeType === 3 )
{
return e;
}
if ( $.trim( $el.text() ) )
{
return findLastTextNode( $el.contents().last(), $top );
}
}
p = getPrevNode( e );
while ( !p )
{
$el = $el.parent();
if ( $el.is( $top ) || !$el.length )
{
return false;
}
p = getPrevNode( $el[0] );
}
if ( p )
{
return findLastTextNode( $(p), $top );
}
}
return false;
}
function getElement( e, $i )
{
if ( !e )
{
return false;
}
if ( typeof e === 'string' )
{
e = $(e, $i);
return ( e.length )
? e
: false;
}
return !e.jquery
? false
: e;
}
function getTrueInnerHeight( $el )
{
var h = $el.innerHeight(),
a = [ 'paddingTop', 'paddingBottom' ];

for ( var z = 0, l = a.length; z < l; z++ )
{
var m = parseInt( $el.css( a[ z ] ), 10 );
if ( isNaN( m ) )
{
m = 0;
}
h -= m;
}
return h;
}

//  override jQuery.html
var _orgHtml = $.fn.html;
$.fn.html = function( str )
{
if ( str != undef && !$.isFunction( str ) && this.data( 'dotdotdot' ) )
{
return this.trigger( 'update', [ str ] );
}
return _orgHtml.apply( this, arguments );
};

//  override jQuery.text
var _orgText = $.fn.text;
$.fn.text = function( str )
{
if ( str != undef && !$.isFunction( str ) && this.data( 'dotdotdot' ) )
{
str = $( '<div />' ).text( str ).html();
return this.trigger( 'update', [ str ] );
}
return _orgText.apply( this, arguments );
};


})( jQuery );

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//! eventify.js //////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function mainEventify(settings) {   
// load user settings
 moment.locale(settings.locale);
if (settings.theme != "") {
    settings.theme = '-'+settings.theme;
}

function sortByStartTimes(a,b) {
if(a.start < b.start) return -1;
if(a.start > b.start) return 1;
return 0;
}

var data = $(''+settings.div.selector+' .ei-event').map(function() {
var $item = $(this);
//  collect data from html
return {
start: moment($item.data('start')), 
end: moment($item.data('end')),
name: $item.find(".ei-name").text(),
description: $item.find(".ei-description").text(),
loc: $item.data('loc')
};
}).get();

// sort collected data by start date and time
data.sort(sortByStartTimes);

var currentDate = moment();

// theme 
$(settings.div.selector).attr("id","ei-events"+settings.theme+"");

// get actual events for month and year
function getEvents(data, date) {
var out = ['<div id="ei-events'+settings.theme+'"><div class="ei-nav-container">', '<h2>'+date.format('MMMM')+' '+date.year()+'</h2>','<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left ei-arrow-left"></i><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right ei-arrow-right"></i>', '</div>', '<div class="ei-events-container">'];

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
if (date.month() === data[i].start.month() && date.year() === data[i].start.year() && data[i].start.date >= currentDate.date) {
out.push('<div class="ei-event">');
out.push('<div class="ei-date">');
out.push('<div class="ei-day">'+data[i].start.date()+'</div>');
out.push('<div class="ei-day_end">- '+data[i].end.date()+'</div>');
out.push('<div class="ei-month">'+data[i].start.format('MMM')+'</div>');
out.push('</div>');
out.push('<div class="ei-content">');
out.push('<div class="ei-name">'+data[i].name+'</div>');
out.push('<div class="ei-time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> '+data[i].start.format('HH:mm')+'  &nbsp; &nbsp; <i class="fa fa-location-arrow"></i> '+data[i].loc+'</div>');
out.push('<div class="ei-description">'+data[i].description+'</div>');      
out.push('</div>'); 
out.push('</div>'); 
}
}

out.push('</div>', '</div>');
out = out.join('\n');
$("div"+settings.div.selector+settings.theme+"").replaceWith(out);

$( ".ei-arrow-left" ).click(function() {
getEvents(data,currentDate.add({months:-1}));
});

$( ".ei-arrow-right" ).click(function() {
getEvents(data,currentDate.add({months:1}));
});

// Dot Dot Dot plugin init
$(".ei-description").dotdotdot({
//  settings
ellipsis    : '... ',
});
}

// write initial data on page load
getEvents(data, currentDate);

}   
(function ($) {

$.fn.eventify = function(options) {    
var settings = $.extend({
// Default settings
div: "#ei-events",
locale: "en",
theme: ""
}, options );

return mainEventify({
div: $(this),
locale: settings.locale,
theme: settings.theme
});
};
}( jQuery ));
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't trying a archieve, I want the link to function in: <div class="ei-name"><a href="zwerge.html">Theater für Zwerge</a></div> thats all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to modify [this line](https://github.com/dellax/eventify/blob/0c6154e5a61784af45b0a68632bbcb53e9528e1c/js/eventify.js#L697), from

```
name: $item.find(".ei-name").text(),
```

to

```
name: $item.find(".ei-name").html(),
```

for element `<div class="ei-name"><a href="zwerge.html">Theater für Zwerge</a></div>`

`.text()` return text `Theater für Zwerge`

`.html()` return  `<a href="zwerge.html">Theater für Zwerge</a>`

Comment: thanks for the quick help, problem is solved

Comment: you're welcome, please mark the answer as correct.